# How would we know if an interhalogen compound would be a gas/liquid at a particular temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Ex- how can we understand that ClF is a gas @ 298K? Is there some logic behind it? Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that chlorine is a gas then you can infer that ClF is also a gas.  The most important intermolecular force in interhalogens is dispersion.  Chlorine has stronger dispersion forces than ClF.  The dipole-dipole forces can be neglected in almost all cases.